# Javascript file path after rewriting dynamic url

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have these rewrite rules in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^product_info/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ /product_info.php?item_id=$1&item_name=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^product_info/ - [L,NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Everything worked fine, until rewriting url. Css,js, images are not loading anymore, so I changed url path by  adding / at very beginning:

```
<link href = "/Style/style.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" />
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/navigation.js"></script>
<script src='/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
<script src='/js/jquery.elevatezoom.js'></script>  <----- NOT WOKRKING
```

That fixed my problem. But for some reason `jquery.elevatezoom.js` is still not working, but everything else is just fine.

I'm using `jquery.elevatezoom.js` in this page:

`/product_info.php?item_id=451&item_name=Bicycle`

After rewriting url -> `/product_info/451/Bicycle`

Js zoom usage in `product_info.php`:

```
<script>
    $("#product_pix").elevateZoom();
</script>
```

Even an absolute path is not fixing the problem.

How can a fix that problem?

Comment: 404 not found when i ran your snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that, your relative URIs have their base changed. Originally, the base is `/` when the page is `/product_info.php`, and the browser properly fills in relative links with the `/` base. But when the browser goes to a page like `/product_info/foo/bar` the base suddenly becomes `/product_info/foo/bar` and it tries to append that in front of all relative URLs and thus none of them load.

You can either make your links absolute, or change the URI base in the header of your pages (inbetween the `<head> </head>` tags):

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: <base href="/"> fixed the problem! Thanks :)